# unable to insert date into SQL using stored procedure from VB.NET form

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I try to inset date into SQL server from textfield. I already tried to convert it but I always keep receiving same error:

> Stored procedure 'XYZ' expects parameter ... which was not supplied.

Before I pass value of date to SQL Server I convert it into date:

```
upis.parameters.AddWithValue("@datum_start", DateValue(Datum_start.text))
```

I captured SQL Event with Profiler and I see that form passes value:

```
exec sp_executesql N'_osoba_zivotopis_test',N'@guid_kandidata nvarchar(36),@datum_start nvarchar(10),@datum_kraj nvarchar(10),@vodece int,@trenutno int',@guid_kandidata=N'24C40512-7292-403D-8C08-EEEA2C81EC7D',@datum_start=N'15.02.2012',@datum_kraj=N'01.10.2012',@vodece=0,@trenutno=0
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you post the VB.net code? There must be something missing...

Comment: How are the stored procedure parameters defined? It looks like you're trying to pass a date to a nvarchar(10)?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sankaras, but problem was on the other side.

After writting 305 lines of code I missed to add code in stored procedure definition in my VB.NET code behind file
`upis.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`

When I defined `CommandType` everything works fine.

.NET knows to pass date value to SQL date data. Even I collect it in my form in local code environment .NET knows how to pass it and SQL knows how to handle it without `convert(date,<varchar/nvarchar>,110)`

I saw it after 10 minutes but I had to wait for 8 hours for post the answer...

Thank you guys.